# how to check whether mod_rewrite is enabled in live server extension of vscode or not, as I am not using xampp or wamp as server

Tags: php, html, mode, liveserver

This is the live server extension in which I have to check whether mode_rewrite is enabled or not. How can I check that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to settings -> extension settings --> Lieve server -settings https --> enable value (true)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhhRS.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for replying Rouidjel. When I am changing enable to true, it is giving me error of "This site can’t provide a secure connection.127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". Can you plz tell, what to do now?